# Check whether Column value is influencing Row Value in R

Tags: r

I'd like to compare two rows and determine whether a column is influencing the value.

For example, let's say I have the following data table in R:

```
 Volume   |        Buyer 
-------------------------------
  100     |       0
  100     |       A
  200     |       0
  200     |       0
```

Now, comparing rows 2 and 3 we see that when the Buyer is A, the row value of 3 changes, so I can say that the Buyer influenced the value in the Volume column. Is there a quick/easy way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with base R. Object `test` just tests for when the volume changes and helps get corresponding buyer. It'd help to know what output structure you want.

```
df <- data.frame(Volume = c(100, 100, 200, 200),
                 Buyer = c(0, "A", 0, 0),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

test <- diff(df$Volume) > 0

influential_buyers <- unique(df$Buyer[test])

influential_buyers
[1] "A"

sum(test) # gives number of total changes
[1] 1

which(test) # gives row number of changes
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I forgot to mention in my original post, but is there a way to check which rows the changes occur in? In my data table the changes occur many times so I'd like a way to record which rows these changes occur (E.g. I'd  like to record that a change occurs in row 2 in the example above)

Comment: Actually, if there is a way to record the total number of row changes in the data table instead of recording each row number individually then that would also work even better if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a graph. This would allow you to see easily, not only which buyer is having an effect, but also the extent of the effect.

**Recreate code**

Note: I expanded your toy example a little to better illustrate the idea

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Volume = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 250, 250),
  Buyer = LETTERS[1:7],
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

**Code**

```
ggplot(df, aes(Buyer, c(0, diff(df$Volume)))) +
  geom_count() +
  ylab("Buyer effect") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**Graph**

[image]